# Android Fragments onBackPressed closes app?

Tags: android, android-fragments

Here is what I do

```
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = activity.getSupportFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction transaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    transaction.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.slide_in_right, R.anim.slide_out_left, R.anim.slide_out_right, R.anim.slide_in_left);

    transaction.addToBackStack(null);
    transaction.add(R.id.content, fragment);
    transaction.show(fragment);
    transaction.commit();
```

When I call this method the `fragment` gets added to the `backstack` (count != 0), and even with this when I click `physical Back button` the app just closes. any ideas ?

EDIT:

When I am on the second fragment and call `popbackstackimmediate` it closes normally as expected, and goes back to previous fragment

Comment: If it is the only fragment in the backstack it is the expected behaviour

Comment: No there is more than one

Answer (score 0):

You should add to backStack the the new Fragment.

```
transaction.addToBackStack(YourFragment.class.getName())
                .add(R.id.content_fragment, yourFragment, YourFragment.class.getName())
                .commit();
```

Hope it helps you!

Comment: transaction.addToBackStack(null) is similar to this, it just doesn't take a tag string but null, I tried that also

Comment: Do You add the fragment from activity or other fragment?. You can try replace instead of add.

Comment: it's from a fragment, unfortunately replace doest work either

Comment: Ok. Then, you should notify to FragmentActivity and from the activity put the new fragment. Create a method in your activity that put your new Fragment and call this method.